# How do I stop the toilet seat from continuously sliding to the right every time it is used?

Tags: toilet

I don't know why the seat keeps moving. I slide it left and it moves to the right every time. Now I definitely see similar questions on here, but the people say they tighten it and it gets loose again. My problem is, I don't know what they're tightening and where to find it. Because I don't see any screws.

Comment: Edit your post to add photos of where the seat connects to the toilet, top and bottom.

Comment: The heads of the screws / bolts are often concealed under covers just behind the seat itself, with the seat closed. They often just snap open to reveal the place you would apply a screwdriver. Don't over-tighten - plastic ones will break (which is good, because...) metal ones will break the toilet (much worse.) Though for the most part metal screws are *usually* paired with plastic nuts these days (less likely to either rust solid or break the toilet) but older ones may be all metal (the good ones will be brass/bronze so they don't rust. The bad ones will be a rusted mess of steel.

Comment: Hold your left hand on the top of your head as you are sitting down.

Answer (score 2):

Standard toilets in my area tighten from below, with a thumb-turn nut located between the tank and bowl. You can only see and access the nuts from the bottom looking up.

That being said, there are many different types of toilets and this may not apply to yours.

Comment: If the bolts are REALLY loose, you may need to use a screwdriver on the heads while you hold the thumbscrews or wingnuts on the bottom. Each bolt head is usually hidden behind a plastic cover, which simply pries up from above.

Comment: In my experience the special nuts below on each side have a projecting tab which contacts a surface on the toilet preventing the nut from spinning even without a wrench. I usually use a large screwdriver on the tops of the bolts. If the bolts do need to be restrained, usually a wrench is not needed. These are often plastic bolts so don't overtighten them. These always loosen with use so expect to have to do this every so often.